# Get the query parameter passed to retrofit inside onResponse method inside callback

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, retrofit2

I have a requirement to use the query parameter that is passed inside retrofit query inside onResponse if it is successful. I can't use global variable as it will change before getting the response.

Comment: you should include some examples. With few information it is impossible to figure out what are you trying to do.

Comment: I am passing a id as query for retrofit get method. I want the same id inside onResponse of that get query

Answer (score 2):

The onResponse method gives you the original call related to that response:

```
call!!.request()
```

the request contains the url related to that particular response, the headers and, if present, the body.

If you parse those data you can get the original parameters

Answer (score 1):

call.request().url().queryParameter("id") this solved the problem

Comment: edit your original question and include this solution, it is clearer for people visiting the page